Memory Issue with KMM on iOS
I migrated my app to Koin and K2 a while back. I'm see these errors consistently but I'm unable to figure out what the root cause is. I know it's a memory issue but that's about it
EXC_BAD_ACCESS
Exception 1, Code 1, Subcode 16 >
KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x10.

Two common culprits are
MutableStateFlow for some reason
private val _authState = MutableStateFlow<AuthState>(UnAuthenticated)

GraphQL calls with Apollo wrapper
suspend fun <Data : Query.Data> query(
        query: Query<Data>,
        fetchPolicy: FetchPolicy = FetchPolicy.NetworkFirst,
        retryStrategy: RetryStrategy = RetryStrategy.Retry()
    ): ApolloResponse<Data>


Are you seeing them locally or only from crash reports? If you can get them locally, even if not consistently, then you'll want to A/B test some things.
Assuming you get them locally, I'd try without the K2 compiler. It's "stable", but that doesn't mean "perfect". It's pretty newly the default for native.
Koin doesn't do anything "system-level" in Kotlin. Coroutines can interact with native threading and probably other things. Apollo may also.
Also, make sure to bump up to the latest point releases. If you're using Kotlin 2.0, you might consider 1.9.24 for now.
Of course, if you can isolate the issue, bug reports make the platform better. If you can trim down a repro and report the issue, that's good for everybody.
But, to address the basic situation first, EXC_BAD_ACCESS is a system-level thing. Often attempting to access deallocated memory. Finding the exact cause can be very difficult because you generally won't get a valid Kotlin stack trace. You generally need to trim code to experiment and isolate the cause. I would guess Apollo is using a lot of Coroutines under the hood, so if you can repro with MutableStateFlow directly, you might be able to narrow down a root cause.
